# Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Tags: php

necesito ayuda con el siguiente codigo, no se conecta a la base de datos que cree en phpMyAdmin, me aparece el error:

Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

codigo:

```
   // Conectar con el servidor de base de datos
      $conexion = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "viviendas")
         or die ("No se puede conectar con el servidor");

   // Seleccionar base de datos
      mysqli_select_db ("viviendas")
         or die ("No se puede seleccionar la base de datos");

   // Enviar consulta
      $instruccion = "select * from viviendas order by precio asc";
      $consulta = mysqli_query ($instruccion, $conexion)
         or die ("Fallo en la consulta");
```

si me pueden ayudar muchas gracias

Comment: Te falta pasar primero la conexión https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.select-db.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es porque la función `mysqli_select_db` necesita como parámetro tu conexión además del nombre de la base de datos que quieres seleccionar ([documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php)):

En tu caso:

```
   // Conectar con el servidor de base de datos
      $conexion = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "viviendas")
         or die ("No se puede conectar con el servidor");

   // Seleccionar base de datos
      mysqli_select_db ($conexion,"viviendas")
         or die ("No se puede seleccionar la base de datos");

   // Enviar consulta
      $instruccion = "select * from viviendas order by precio asc";
      $consulta = mysqli_query ($instruccion, $conexion)
         or die ("Fallo en la consulta");
```

Comment: Me sirvio mucho tu ayuda, muchas gracias por solucionar mi problema

Comment: @Raul si la respuesta te fué útil, la mejor forma de agradecer es marcarla como aceptada